# HTML Email Template has additional empty space in html tag

Tags: html, css, email

I'm making email template which generated by drag and drop function.
I'm new on this, and I followed this tutorial [link](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919)

But, when I sent the email, sometimes I got additional space in one of html tag. And I also got extra "+" sign at one of url link or image src.

My HTML:

```
<div style="inline-styles-here">
   <img src="abc.com/open_link.php" class="CToWUd">
</div>
```

Result:

```
 <div><!-- inline styles is missing -->
     <img src="abc.com/open_li+nk.php" class="CToWUd"><!-- There is + at the src link -->
 < /div> <!-- There is space in the closing tag -->
```

And sometimes, I also got one of my inline styles was missing.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You have given file name as `<img src="abc.com/open_li+nk.php" class="CToWUd">`

cant' it be `<img src="abc.com/open_link.php" class="CToWUd">`?

to remove additional space,

```
  <table width="600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="bg-color1" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
<tbody>
  <tr><td>Your email content</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

You can refer [this link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/)

hope this helps.